# How can I run a Perl script on Mac OS X?

Tags: perl, macos

How do I run a Perl script on OS X?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can run your `Perl` script by invoking the `Perl` interpreter and giving your file as input:

```
perl myprogram.pl
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to pass `-w`, at least when running your own Perl code: `perl -w myprogram.pl`.

Comment: FYI the `-w` flag adds a whole mess of warnings and such if your syntax is wonky.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to run a perl script is with the option:

```
perl myprogram.pl
```

However, you may find it more useful to add a shebang line at the top of the perl file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello World!\n";
```

In order to *execute* this script, you need to add execute permissions to your program.  Run:

```
chmod +x myprogram.pl
```

Now, in order to run your script, you can simply type:

```
./myprogram.pl
```

Answer (score 17):

A good tutorial on Perl in OSX can be found here:

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.18/18.09/PerlforMacOSX/index.html

A generic documentation on executing Perl code is of course [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

To answer your question directly:

You can run a perl script on any Unix system by either having the code evaluated and executed from command line:

```
perl -e 'print "Hello World\n"';
```

Or you can save your Perl script to a file (customarily having `.pl` extension, say `script1.pl` and with the first line being `#!/usr/bin/perl`) and then you can execute it as any Unix program (after setting proper execute permissions)

```
/path/to/script/script1.pl
```

You can also execute a script from a file by running perl interpreter as the command and giving the script as a parameter (in this case execute permissions to the script are not needed):

```
perl /path/to/script/script1.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the whole directory didn't work for me but I just did

```
perl ~/Desktop/file.pl
```

(you could also use any folder that is in your user-folder after the ~/)